# Transaction NET usage on eosx.io and 'get account' don't match

Tags: transactions, resources, net

When my account did not have enough NET resource ( 12 bytes limit at that moment) and I sent a transaction, I got an error
`transaction net usage is too high: 120 > 12`

I bought NET resource and sent again the transaction which is the last one  in [this block](https://jungle.eosx.io/block/55056433).
And then I see that the used net bandwith actually grew by 120 bytes in `get account` result.

My question is why is it shown `15 B` in eosx.io report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found the answer.
Capital `B` mean 8-byte words. That's a `net_usage_words` field in processed transaction.
You can look at [this](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/2000) also.